# Solving non-linear equations

Tags: equation-solving

I´m new in coding and I need to solve a set of non linear equations. It´s a set of 3J equations in 2J + 2 unknowns: the J unknown values of βj, the J unknown values of μj, and the 2 unknown independent components of a unit vector u. I don´t know any reasonable starting values, so when I run my code I always got an error message that a single jacobian was encountered. The code is for J=2 but also I want to expand the system to J=10 (data already contained in variable mij.). Can anybody please help me solve these equations?

```
mij = {{1.3067138428220,2.4075852527272,3.338703707857},{1.1957072133028,1.1939672521530,1.6554978836236},{1.1634791565792,0.8419988047084135,1.167334669041159}, {1.1496251650317197,0.685390009666267,0.9499801680166198}, {1.1490966939110652,0.6854848022568772,0.95028283634603}, {1.1493538354209782,0.6903291660034211,0.9570670177527794}, {1.1379451243779293,0.568060100622182,0.7875227640478683},{1.132778443580569,0.5101431661797775,0.7071428683809919}, {1.1287596736205838,0.46716991388721535,0.6475558488667996}, {1.1218181817546011, 0.3911657652798617,0.5421184173117446}}; 
ni = {1.658747300215982695,5.231101511879049546,7.03671706263498898};
pi = {-0.041885130546511,-0.03337884298016919755,-0.016552882029393285823516};
FindRoot[
{ni[[1]] + muj1 ui1 - mij[[1, 1]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[1]]) == 0, 
ni[[2]] + muj1 ui1 - mij[[1, 2]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[2]]) == 0, 
ni[[3]] + muj1 ui1 - mij[[1, 3]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[3]]) == 0, 
ni[[1]] + muj2 ui2 - mij[[2, 1]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[1]]) == 0, 
ni[[2]] + muj2 ui2 - mij[[2, 2]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[2]]) == 0, 
ni[[3]] + muj2 ui2 - mij[[2, 3]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[3]]) == 0}, 
{{muj1, RandomReal[]}, {muj2, RandomReal[]}, {ui1, RandomReal[]}, {ui2,   RandomReal[]}, {betaj1, RandomReal[]}, {betaj2, RandomReal[]}}];
```

These are the original eq from the publication:
[image: original eq]

Thanks for all your efforts, but some answers a kind of too sophisticated for me, I´m just a geologist ;) I´ve tried a lot, but still I cannot solve them. I believe, I don´t know how to arrange the eqs. In addition, the publication says that I can calculate the "2 unknown independent components" of the unit vector ui. When i=3, how do I get this "known component"? ui is supposed to be a unit vector along a mixing line, from which one side is known. 
I´ve tried a set up with j=3 to get 9 eqs and 9 variables, also got some more reasonable starting parameters, but I´m still stucked.

```
mij = {{1.3067138428220, 2.4075852527272, 
3.338703707857}, {1.1957072133028, 1.1939672521530, 
1.6554978836236}, {1.1634791565792, 0.8419988047084135, 
1.167334669041159}, {1.1496251650317197, 0.685390009666267, 
0.9499801680166198}, {1.1490966939110652, 0.6854848022568772, 
0.95028283634603}, {1.1493538354209782, 0.6903291660034211, 
0.9570670177527794}, {1.1379451243779293, 0.568060100622182, 
0.7875227640478683}, {1.132778443580569, 0.5101431661797775, 
0.7071428683809919}, {1.1287596736205838, 0.46716991388721535, 
0.6475558488667996}, {1.1218181817546011, 0.3911657652798617, 
0.5421184173117446}};
ni = {1.658747300215982695, 5.231101511879049546, 7.03671706263498898};
pi = {-0.041885130546511, -0.03337884298016919755, \
-0.016552882029393285823516};
FindRoot[
{
ni[[1]] + müj1 ui1 - mij2[[1, 1]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[1]]) == 0
, ni[[2]] + müj1 ui2 - mij2[[1, 2]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[2]]) == 0
, ni[[3]] + müj1 ui3 - mij2[[1, 3]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[3]]) == 0

, ni[[1]] + müj2 ui1 - mij2[[2, 1]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[1]]) == 0
, ni[[2]] + müj2 ui2 - mij2[[2, 2]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[2]]) == 0
, ni[[3]] + müj2 ui3 - mij2[[2, 3]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[3]]) == 0

, ni[[1]] + müj3 ui1 - mij2[[3, 1]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[1]]) == 0
, ni[[2]] + müj3 ui2 - mij2[[3, 2]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[2]]) == 0
, ni[[3]] + müj3 ui3 - mij2[[3, 3]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[3]]) == 0
}
, {{müj1, -0.150093}, {ui1, 0.48}, {ui2, 17.7990}, {betaj1, 
1.8125454}, {müj2, -0.2703640493}, {müj3, -0.27055}, {ui3, 
23.942731}, {betaj2, 1.801259006161}, {betaj3, 1.80586513960}}
, MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

Comment: You don't have enough unknowns as currently stated. Yes, you have six unknowns for six equations, but `muj1 ui1` always appears in that combination, as does `muj2 ui2`. So you can replace those each with a single parameter.

Comment: Thank, but sorry, I don´t understand it...when I replace the parameters I´ve got more eqs than unknowns plus I want to know muj and ui and not their products. I´ve posted the original eqs, maybe my coding of the eqs is the problem?

Comment: Yes, your code is wrong. Each of your lines uses muj1 ui1, when you want those to change.

Comment: Even if you fix your code, you still can't solve that equation as it stands - you need to decide with subset of equations you want to solve, such that #equations = #unknowns.

Comment: There is something amiss in that, as noted by @KraZug, it is not possible to separate out the factors in those mu-times-u products. So rechecking the equations is in order. Also, since there seem to be many more rows to `mij`, probably what is wanted is a best-fit rather than an exact solution to a subset (granted, the latter might be useful for initial guesses for the former).

Answer (score 3):

I will not re-copy the data nor the equations.

The second way you have written your equations is correct. You have 9 equations and 9 unknowns.

`FindRoot` is having trouble finding a solution.

### Step 1 - FindMinimum

Recast the problem and use `FindMinimum`. We will take the left hand side of the equations, square them and add them, and then ask `FindMinimum` to determine the parameters that will minimize that expression.

This is more or less equivalent to setting each sub-expresion to zero.

```
solMin = FindMinimum[
  (ni[[1]] + müj1 ui1 - 
      mij2[[1, 1]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[1]]))^2 + (ni[[2]] + müj1 ui2 - 
      mij2[[1, 2]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[2]]))^2 + (ni[[3]] + müj1 ui3 - 
      mij2[[1, 3]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[3]]))^2 + (ni[[1]] + müj2 ui1 - 
      mij2[[2, 1]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[1]]))^2 + (ni[[2]] + müj2 ui2 - 
      mij2[[2, 2]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[2]]))^2 + (ni[[3]] + müj2 ui3 - 
      mij2[[2, 3]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[3]]))^2 + (ni[[1]] + müj3 ui1 - 
      mij2[[3, 1]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[1]]))^2 + (ni[[2]] + müj3 ui2 - 
      mij2[[3, 2]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[2]]))^2 + (ni[[3]] + müj3 ui3 - 
      mij2[[3, 3]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[3]]))^2,
  {
   {müj1, -0.150093}, {müj2, -0.2703640493}, {müj3, -0.27055},
   {ui1, 0.48}, {ui2, 17.7990}, {ui3, 23.942731},
   {betaj1, 1.8125454}, {betaj2, 1.801259006161}, {betaj3, 
    1.80586513960}
   }
  ]

(* {1.07279*10^-9, {müj1 -> -0.145231, müj2 -> -0.215279, 
  müj3 -> -0.23559, ui1 -> 1.71491, ui2 -> 18.4086, ui3 -> 24.7634, 
  betaj1 -> 1.81089, betaj2 -> 1.80424, betaj3 -> 1.80261}} *)
```

In order to validate the solution substitue the answer into the left hand side of the equations.

```
leftHandSide = {
   ni[[1]] + müj1 ui1 - mij2[[1, 1]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[1]]), 
   ni[[2]] + müj1 ui2 - mij2[[1, 2]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[2]]), 
   ni[[3]] + müj1 ui3 - mij2[[1, 3]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[3]]), 
   ni[[1]] + müj2 ui1 - mij2[[2, 1]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[1]]), 
   ni[[2]] + müj2 ui2 - mij2[[2, 2]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[2]]), 
   ni[[3]] + müj2 ui3 - mij2[[2, 3]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[3]]), 
   ni[[1]] + müj3 ui1 - mij2[[3, 1]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[1]]), 
   ni[[2]] + müj3 ui2 - mij2[[3, 2]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[2]]), 
   ni[[3]] + müj3 ui3 - mij2[[3, 3]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[3]])
   };

leftHandSide /. solMin[[2]]

(* {5.47011*10^-6, -7.00355*10^-6, 
 4.8275*10^-6, -8.14193*10^-6, 0.0000198635, -0.0000142023, 
 4.0679*10^-6, -0.0000138336, 0.000010002} *)
```

The answer is zero to within about 2*10-5.

### Step 2 - Cross Correlation and FindRoot

There is a terrible cross-correlation between the parameters.

You can validate this by changing the starting points. You get a different answer but are still minimize the equations.

Here we will take the original `FindRoot` parameter and impose the starting value for müj1 in the first two equations.

```
solRoot = FindRoot[
  {
   ni[[1]] + -0.150093 ui1 - mij2[[1, 1]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[1]]) == 0, 
   ni[[2]] + -0.150093 ui2 - mij2[[1, 2]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[2]]) == 0, 
   ni[[3]] + müj1 ui3 - mij2[[1, 3]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[3]]) == 0, 
   ni[[1]] + müj2 ui1 - mij2[[2, 1]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[1]]) == 0, 
   ni[[2]] + müj2 ui2 - mij2[[2, 2]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[2]]) == 0, 
   ni[[3]] + müj2 ui3 - mij2[[2, 3]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[3]]) == 0, 
   ni[[1]] + müj3 ui1 - mij2[[3, 1]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[1]]) == 0, 
   ni[[2]] + müj3 ui2 - mij2[[3, 2]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[2]]) == 0, 
   ni[[3]] + müj3 ui3 - mij2[[3, 3]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[3]]) == 0
   },
  {
   {müj1, -0.150093}, {müj2, -0.2703640493}, {müj3, -0.27055},
   {ui1, 0.48}, {ui2, 17.7990}, {ui3, 23.942731},
   {betaj1, 1.8125454}, {betaj2, 1.801259006161}, {betaj3, 
    1.80586513960}
   },
  MaxIterations -> 10000
  ]

(* {müj1 -> -0.150102, müj2 -> -0.22251, müj3 -> -0.243507, 
 ui1 -> 1.65702, ui2 -> 17.8089, ui3 -> 23.9575, betaj1 -> 1.81694, 
 betaj2 -> 1.81301, betaj3 -> 1.81258} *)
```

Now test the result.

```
leftHandSide /. solRoot

(* {-0.0000153686, -0.000165174, 0., -5.55112*10^-17, \
-4.44089*10^-16, 0., 3.33067*10^-16, 0., 0.} *)
```

You could equally well have used -0.145231 for the value of müj1 and get an equally good answer.

```
solRoot = FindRoot[
  {
   ni[[1]] + -0.145231 ui1 - mij2[[1, 1]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[1]]) == 0, 
   ni[[2]] + -0.145231 ui2 - mij2[[1, 2]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[2]]) == 0, 
   ni[[3]] + müj1 ui3 - mij2[[1, 3]] E^(-betaj1 pi[[3]]) == 0, 
   ni[[1]] + müj2 ui1 - mij2[[2, 1]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[1]]) == 0, 
   ni[[2]] + müj2 ui2 - mij2[[2, 2]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[2]]) == 0, 
   ni[[3]] + müj2 ui3 - mij2[[2, 3]] E^(-betaj2 pi[[3]]) == 0, 
   ni[[1]] + müj3 ui1 - mij2[[3, 1]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[1]]) == 0, 
   ni[[2]] + müj3 ui2 - mij2[[3, 2]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[2]]) == 0, 
   ni[[3]] + müj3 ui3 - mij2[[3, 3]] E^(-betaj3 pi[[3]]) == 0
   },
  {
   {müj1, -0.145231}, {müj2, -0.2703640493}, {müj3, -0.27055},
   {ui1, 0.48}, {ui2, 17.7990}, {ui3, 23.942731},
   {betaj1, 1.8125454}, {betaj2, 1.801259006161}, {betaj3, 
    1.80586513960}
   },
  MaxIterations -> 10000
  ]

(* {müj1 -> -0.14524, müj2 -> -0.215302, müj3 -> -0.235619, 
 ui1 -> 1.71249, ui2 -> 18.4051, ui3 -> 24.7595, betaj1 -> 1.81694, 
 betaj2 -> 1.81301, betaj3 -> 1.81258} *)
```

Virtually identical results with a different `müj1`.

### Summary

The problem is ill-conditioned. You might as well impose the value of one of the product terms and then use `FindRoot` to determine the other values.

There is not sufficient information to extract nine independent parameters from the data and equations.

Comment: Hi Guys, hi Jack! Thanks for all your efforts. I´ve processed the data from Jacks solution through the upcoming steps, but the results are desperate incorrect. I will try to find another approach for my work than solving these horrible eqs. Thanks @all!